# How to create a session and let the user fill data later

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

How do I create a a session that captures user input where by the user can come  back and continue from where they had stop while filling a form. Any help thank you in advance because I have no idea on what is the best way to do it

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should be storing the information in the database (server side), but if you want it to persist on the client side( across browser sessions) you can use `localStorage`

To read more about localStorage  you can check [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

There are other client-side storage techniques, you can choose depending upon your requirement.

1. Cookies
2. sessionStorage
3. IndexedDB

I suggest you to check this link also for the comparison. [**Client-Side Storage Technology**](https://mattwest.design/choosing-the-best-client-side-storage-technology-for-your-project)

Answer (score 0):

The standard usage of the word "session" in the client-server model usually describes a scenario where HTTP cookies or cryptography is used to track the visits of a particular user to a site. These are the bare-metal technologies behind user authentication.

The "sessions" you mean in your question are for tracking the continuation of data a user may have been submitted.

**Do it server side**

1. Keeps track of the data a user may have submitted.
2. Save whatever part of the data user maybe submitting.
3. Load this data back when you serve the form to thew user gain.

**Do it client side**

1. Save the user data in the Local Storage of the client's browser.
2. Look for this data every time the from is loaded to the browser.

However, the server side approach is the most reliable and would provide a guarantee that the data will persist across any time span as long as the server side data is preserved.